# If statement in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, boolean

I found that excel has an if feature that is

```
= IF(booleanExpression, trueValue, falseValue)
```

I am trying to use it but i think there is something wrong with my boolean statement.

I have:

```
=IF ( ( ((.8*P20)>(1.35*H20)) AND ( (.8*P20)<(2*H20))), (.8*P20), (1.35*H20))
```

I'm assuming my problem is with the AND part. Is there a way i can check two conditions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the **AND** is different:

***=IF(AND(statement1, statement2), v_if_true, v_if_false)***

VBA uses **AND** differently:

***If statement1 AND statement2 Then***

Answer (score 1):

Just use `AND` to equate multiple values:

```
=IF(AND(0.8 * P20 > 1.35 * H20, 0.8 * P20 < 2 * H20), 0.8 * P20, 1.35 * H20)
```

Btw your use of brackets was a bit excessive so I've removed them here.

See this Microsoft article for more information on `AND`: https://support.office.com/en-my/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9

Comment: I'm always excessive haha but this worked. I was using the AND operator incorrectly